# Usage of int instead of char

Tags: c, char, eof, unsigned-char, integer-promotion

I've got a copy of the book "The C Programming Language", and in one of the first chapters it shows a short example of a code that copies characters from stdin to stdout. Here is the code:

```
main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

The writer then said, he used int instead of char because char isn't big enough to hold EOF.
But when I tried it with char, it worked in the same way, even with ctrl+z.
Stack says it’s a duplicate, so I ask shortly:

Why using ‘char’ is wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to type the character ÿ on your keyboard?  Or maybe just copy-and-paste it out of this comment.  Anyway, try running your `char`-using program with ÿ as input if you can.  Your program will probably stop reading, as if you had typed control-Z.

Comment: In general, when working with C or C++, "it works for me" is not a good enough reason to justify doing something a certain way.  Undefined Behavior can produce many different outcomes, including code that appears to work 99% of the time.

Comment: @SteveSummit: whether that works depends on whether the codeset used by the terminal is UTF-8 (it won't) or some single-byte code set such as ISO 8859-15 (it probably will).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I'm gambling on the relative lack of support for UTF-8 in Windows.  Some day I'll have to figure out if there's a UTF-8 use case that tickles the bug.

Comment: @nonamedelete In general, `getchar` can return 257 different things: all 256 possibilities for an 8-bit character value, *plus* the value `EOF`, which is by definition not equal to any valid `char` value.  But type `char` is (usually!) not big enough to hold 257 different values.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Probably not — the 0xFF byte is simply invalid in UTF-8.  Indeed, all the bytes from 0xF5-0xFF cannot occur in valid UTF-8 (and neither can 0xC0 or 0xC1).  0xFFFF might almost work if working with a UTF-16 encoding, but it is a non-character (see [Corrigendum #9](https://www.unicode.org/versions/corrigendum9.html)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, I was afraid of that.  (So how are we supposed to convince the new kids that using `char` here is RONG? :-\ )

Comment: @SteveSummit: I fear that it will require the (mis)reading of binary data rather than keyboard input to generate the problem.  It does get a bit fraught, but using `char` instead of `int` is still wrong, even though it's harder to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd *like* to just point 'em at [the FAQ list](https://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html).  (But if they're not gonna listen to K&R, who am I to imagine they'll listen to me? :-\ )

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: U+FFFF is an non-character, certainly, but `getchar` reads a byte at a time, and lots of UTF-16 codes contain a byte with the value 0xFF, starting with the BOM (which often occupied the first two bytes of a UTF-16 file).

Answer (score 0):

If you will write for example

```
char c;
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
//...
```

when in the condition `c != EOF` the value of the object `c` is promoted to the type `int` and two integers are compared.

The problem with declaring the variable `c` as having the type `char` is that the type `char` can behave either as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char` (depending on a compiler option). If the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char` then the expression `c != EOF` will always evaluate to logical `true`.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard `EOF` is defined the following way

> EOF which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and
> **a negative value**, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream;

So after this assignment

```
c = getchar();
```

when `c` is declared as having the type `char` and the type `char` behaves as the type `unsigned char` then the value of `c` will be a positive value after the integer promotion and hence will not be equal to a negative value.

To simulate the situation just declare the variable `c` as having the type `unsigned char`

```
unsigned char c;
```

Comment: *If the type char behaves as the type unsigned char then the expression c != EOF will always evaluate to true* Yes, although we already know that didn't happen for the OP, who claims that control-Z still works.

Comment: *The problem with declaring the variable c as having the type char is that the type char can behave either as the type signed char or unsigned char* Ah.  So if OP had explicitly used `signed char c` or `unsigned char c`, the program would have been fine? :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit getchar returns an integer value that represents an unsigned character except when EOF occurs. So using unsigned char as I pointed out results in an infinite loop.

Comment: @SteveSummit: On a Unix-like system, control-Z might suspend the current program and return the shell prompt.  The program hasn't exited; it's merely stopped until it is restarted.  I've seen people confused by that.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I thought the OP's report that the program had *not* gone into an infinite loop ruled out that hypothesis.  But Jonathan Leffler's supposition about control-Z on a Unix-like system throws that into doubt.

Comment: @SteveSummit It seems that in his system the type char by default behaves as the type signed char.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I agree.  That's why I suggested typing ÿ.  (Although, as Jonathan Leffler has also pointed out, that might not work, either, on a UTF-8 system.)